# CryptoApi wrap and unwrap keys

Tags: windows, cryptography, cryptoapi

Is there a way to wrap or unwrap keys in **CryptoApi**? I tryed to set the key params `CRYPT_IMPORT_KEY` and `CRYPT_EXPORT_KEY` with the proper function, but I get the error "params undefined".

Other details: 
The program is written in C++, OS: Win7, IDE: Dev-C++
The main headers are `windows.h` and `wincrypt.h`.

When I compile, i get the error " CRYPT_EXPORT_KEY (or CRYPT_IMPORT_KEY) undeclared".

Code I wrote:

```
flags = CRYPT_ENCRYPT | CRYPT_EXPORTABLE | CRYPT_DECRYPT | CRYPT_EXPORT_KEY;
//set the above permission to the session key "dkey"    
CryptSetKeyParam(dKey,KP_PERMISSIONS,(BYTE*)&flags,0);
```

### Update from the comments:

And it compiles! But the programs terminates with the error `NTE_BAD_FLAGS`. It is because of `CRYPT_EXPORT_KEY` flag!

Comment: What language? What library? What OS? Compiler Error or Linker Error or Runtime Error? Also show the code you tried. This is not a Text Message so feel free include relevant details.

Comment: I tried the above code with <windows.h> & <wincrypt.h> included and it compiles fine.

Comment: maybe you use a different compiler.. let me check it!

Comment: which compiler do you use?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 - Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86

Comment: And it compiles! But the programs terminates with the error NTE_BAD_FLAGS. It is because of CRYPT_EXPORT_KEY flag!

Comment: Based on the MSDN documentation, `CryptSetKeyParam` does not support the KP_PERMISSIONS flag, only `CryptGetKeyParam` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs - [CryptSetKeyParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CryptGetKeyParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

When you are using `KP_PERMISSIONS`, the valid set of flags are

```
CRYPT_ARCHIVE
CRYPT_DECRYPT
CRYPT_ENCRYPT
CRYPT_EXPORT
CRYPT_EXPORT_KEY
CRYPT_IMPORT_KEY
CRYPT_MAC
CRYPT_READ
CRYPT_WRITE
```

`CRYPT_EXPORTABLE` is not in this list.

If you check the docs for [CryptGenKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `CRYPT_EXPORTABLE` is a flag which you use while creating the key, so that it can be exported later. It's not required for `CryptSetKeyParam`.

Comment: that's right. CRYPT_EXPORTABLE is used during key generation. But anyway, without it, the program doesn't run!

Comment: What do you mean 'does not run'?

Comment: the program terminates with the error NTE_BAD_FLAGS (80090009)! The flag CRYPT_EXPORT_KEY is not recognised

Comment: Is it the `CryptExportKey` call which fails - if yes - can you show your parameters to `CryptExportKey`

Comment: `CryptExportKey` is a function, and at this point i think it plays the role of `CRYPT_EXPORT_KET`, which is a flag. The function works correctly. For example, i use `CryptExportKey(dKey,dKey,SYMMETRICWRAPKEYBLOB,0,keyBlob,&dwBlobLength))`. If I want to use 'dKey' to wrap keys, i can proceed in this way.